# HUGE Number of MQGET and MQINQS requests logged against a MQ channel

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-8, mq

We have a BatchJob application which is configured in Websphere Application Server (8.0.0.7). The application processes the requests put in the source MQ queue. Through WAS, the MQ queue is polled to see if there are any new requests available for processing.

We have been recently notified by a MQ resource that, there is high CPU resource utilization due to the MQ channel used by our application. When looked at the numbers, the MQGETS and MQINQS requests are humongous. This is not a 1 off incidence. It has always been like that since the day our application was installed. So I believe there is some configuration at Websphere that is causing this high volume of MQGETS and MQINQS requests.

Can somebody give any pointers which configs need to be checked? I am from application development side, so don't have in-detailed knowledge about WAS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the WAS application written? Is it an MDB or an EJB?

Comment: It is an MDB application.